# How to create custom theme using twenty twenty three Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

While creating a custom theme using **Twenty Twenty-Three** WordPress default theme.

I face major changes in the theme as compared to the old theme there are no functions.php files. The whole structure of the theme is changed.I found **theme.json** files, you can check the structure below in the screenshot
[image]

Then again inside the parts folder i found header & footer code pls check below:

```
<!-- wp:group {"layout":{"type":"constrained"}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group">
    <!-- wp:group {"align":"wide","style":{"spacing":{"padding":{"bottom":"var:preset|spacing|40"}}},"layout":{"type":"flex","justifyContent":"space-between"}} -->
    <div class="wp-block-group alignwide" style="padding-bottom:var(--wp--preset--spacing--40)">
        <!-- wp:site-title {"level":0} /-->
        <!-- wp:navigation {"layout":{"type":"flex","setCascadingProperties":true,"justifyContent":"right"}} /-->
    </div>
    <!-- /wp:group -->
</div>
<!-- /wp:group -->
```

**So my question is** can we create a functions.php file and add the scripts, style, and other hooks or should we still use the old theme to create a custom Theme WordPress?

Comment: Yes that will work

Answer (score 0):

Definitely yes! I've created a Twenty-Twenty-Three child theme and added my own function.php and style.css to it - works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Vadim H, I have also created both a Twenty-Twenty-Three child theme and a standalone FSE theme. I added functions.php to both. WordPress should automatically find the file when it is at the theme root (as shown in my screenshot). [See the Developer Resources here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/).

FWIW: I also added some script to the Twenty-Twenty-Three child theme "assets" folder. Here is what my themes looks like, including functions.php

[image: Twenty-Twenty-Three child theme screenshot]

The [Child Theme Configurator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/) can be helpful when starting out with FSE child theme.